Is it true that all abelian p-nilpotent restricted Lie algebras are mirrors of finite abelian p-groups?
Let $k$ be a perfect field of characteristic $p$. A $p$-nilpotent restricted Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ is a Lie algebra with $[p]$-restriction mapping such that $\mathfrak{g}^{[p]^n} = 0$ for some $n \ge 0$.
I found the article
Schneider, Csaba; Usefi, Hamid, The classification of (p)-nilpotent restricted Lie algebras of dimension at most 4, Forum Math. 28, No. 4, 713-727 (2016). ZBL1404.17028.
which includes a classification of such restricted Lie algebras of dimension up to $4$. In these small dimensions, it perfectly mirrors the classification of finite abelian $p$-groups. By this I mean we can define the cyclic $p$-Lie algebra of dimension $n$ as $\mathfrak{c}_n = \langle x_1, \dots, x_n \mid x_i^{[p]} = x_{i+1}, x_{n+1} = x_n^{[p]} = 0\rangle$, and in the article it is proven in an elementary way that all abelian $p$-nilpotent restricted Lie algebras up to dimension 4 have the structure $\prod_n \mathfrak{c}_{n}^{i_n}$. Of course the restricted enveloping algebra of such a product of cyclic Lie algebras is isomorphic (as an associative algebra) to the group algebra of the product of cyclic $p$-groups of appropriate sizes, $k$ being of characteristic $p$.
Are all abelian $p$-nilpotent Lie algebras a product of cyclic algebras? I can imagine that an inductive adaptation of the technique outlined in the article is possible, but I'd love to see a source on this or a counterexample in larger dimension. I can also imagine a proof by simply finding an equivalence of categories of representations of any such Lie algebra with some finite abelian $p$-group and directly applying the classification of finite abelian groups. Hopefully this is not one of those folklore theorems too boring to be published anywhere.

Every finite-dimensional abelian restricted Lie algebra over a perfect field of characteristic $p>0$ actually decomposes as a direct sum of cyclic restricted subalgebras. As a reference for this result, see e.g. the theorem in Section 3.1 of Chapter 4 of the book [Y. Bahturin - A.A. Mikhalev - Petrogradsky- M.V. Zaicev: Infinite-dimensional Lie superalgebras].
It is easy to see that the conclusione is false without the assumption of perfectness of the ground field.

Thanks, I've marked answered, although surely there is a difference in terminology given what I've called 'cyclic'. This is fine though, as any classification of finite indecomposable abelian restricted Lie algebras over a perfect field, which we call cyclic, is suitable for my purposes. I assume cyclic must then include for instance $\langle x,y, z \mid x^p = y, y^p = z, z^p = x \rangle$, which is not p-nilpotent in Schneider and Usefi's definition.

Just chiming back in after I've looked more thoroughly at the source given. Over an algebraically closed field, it is a theorem of Seligman, that there is actually only one indecomposable abelian restricted Lie algebra, which is not p-nilpotent, up to isomorphism, and it is 1-dimensional (so the three dimensional Lie algebra in my previous comment is actually not indecomposable). The structure theory otherwise tells us that all the other indecomposables are cyclic, per my original p-nilpotent definition in the original post. Perfect, non alg. closed fields are insufficient for this conclusion.

In fact, over algebraically closed fields, the only indecomposable finite-dimensional abelian restricted Lie algebra, which is not p-nilpotent, is the 1-dimensional torus. The situation is more complicated over more general perfect fields.
